# How does a community of a Universe Simulator have the same language as its creator?

Tags: culture, universe, strategy

This takes place in the optimistic future. While a war general is strategizing his plans of attack, he rejects using [outdated war games of the past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_wargame), and instead tasks a few members of his team to operate on one of the few universe simulators that the government has.

While the scientists of the team know how to form the civilization, it requires that a few civilizations in the universe speak the same language, follow these social conventions, etc. etc.

How would they direct these civilizations to form the team's desired cultures?

**Just a few Notes:**

- Creating highly-processed or detailed objects is very time-expensive, especially at a mass quantity.
- The techs find it easier and faster for them to set up a small state that turns into a larger "goal state", than starting with the goal state by itself.

Comment: Wouldn't a simulation of current events not just be a standart programm on a machine like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the sim run until the life inside achieves sentience and scholarship. Then inject an archeological find of a "crashed ship" or "previous civilization" that has books and video from the real world. Adjust the materials injected to serve as a basis for how you want them to develop. Then you can get scholars to study them. Eventually, someone will likely try a historical reconstruction, like a Ren Faire today. Inject catastrophes for any culture that doesn't adopt such practices, reward the ones that do.

Answer (score 1):

The creator of the simulation would create a culture around the language, social conventions, etc...

This culture would be composed by books, songs, stories, ... that give hints on how to speak and behave to the new civilization. This culture would give the people of the new civilization the impression that his culture has been around for years so the follow it.

Answer (score 1):

They are set up that way, already in-progress. You don’t run the simulation from the Big Bang and hope you get humans…you set up the simulated planet *with* humans. Language and culture are chosen as well; you have to give them *something* as their “present” state!